# How to connect on MongoDB using R Script? (How to connect Power BI to MongoDB)

Tags: r, mongodb, powerbi

I need to connect Power BI on a MongoDB database, I tried using ODBC, but I have a lot os problems, then, I started to try to connect using R Script, but I still can't.

For Power BI experts, how to connect Power BI to MongoDB?

I tried the following script on Power BI:

```
library("mongolite")
newdb <- mongo(collection= "games", db = "admin", url = "mongodb://mongouser:mongopass@IP:PORT/admin", verbose = TRUE)
```

But I have the following result:

[image]

No collections or registers, but on Robo3T I see 3 collections and some registers.

Answer (score -2):

You have to create an object and then attribute the command `find()` to there.

Like this:

```
library(mongolite)
m <- mongo("customer",url="myurl")
customer <- m$find()
```